# Excel - formula to calculate average for variable number of rows in table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table where the value in column B is the average of some preceding values in column A.

I want to use a named range "DaysToCount" to vary the number of rows used for the average. I've tried using ADDRESS and  CONCATENATE to build the AVERAGE function like this:

```
AVERAGE(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(ROW()-DaysToCount+1,2),":B",ROW())))
```

It gives me a #VALUE error. Using the Evaluate formula tool I can see it evaluates down to 
something like this:

```
AVERAGE("B3:B12")
```

What I want is this:

```
AVERAGE(B3:B12)
```

Is there a way to fix this - or should I try another approach?

Answer (score 1):

The way to use formulas to build cell references inside a function is to use `INDIRECT`. I was able to accomplish my goal using this formula:

```
AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B" & ROW()-DaysToCount+1 & ":B"&ROW()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The short way is something like this.  Let's assume that this formula will be in B7:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B7,(-1 * (DaysToCount-1)),-1,DaysToCount))
```

I don't always like that because of the explicit cell reference there.  But getting rid of that takes a bit more effort.  You can replace it with one of the techniques [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335563/self-reference-for-cell-column-and-row-in-worksheet-functions).

Comment: Thanks for replying and for the link. It led me (indirectly :) to the solution...